# Neo4j Import Job from CSV with ancestory as the relationship

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, neo4j-batch-inserter, large-data

I have a some data that I want to into insert into neo4j.

Initially I made a script to create all the relationships and nodes as a cql file which worked nicely for smaller amount of data-set but when my data set grew my system crashed.

Keep in mind I was using the neo4j-shell to input all the data.

I know I can batch insert the data with the batch importer but my entire data set has only one table with ancestries which I used to create the relationships.

For example 1=> 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3 and so forth.. I converted the data to a .csv and imported it and it worked really nicely and fast I was able to get all the nodes but how do I go about getting the relationships to be created in neo4j with just one table that holds ID,name, and ancestry?

Comment: I think you'll need to give us more information as to your create script...right now we only have a fuzzy idea of what your graph db looks like. If all you need is a single table with a few pieces of data, I've got to ask if neo4j is the right tool for this. I'm also wondering if you're confusing how the data is stored in the db with the output that you want from a query. The output may look just like a single table, but it will be stored as nodes and relationships in the db.

Comment: Yeah sorry if I confused everyone. My script just goes through each record and creates a node and a relationship for it. I handled this using ancestry relationship which made it simple since if I have a child I know it belongs to the parent. I know the values will be stored as nodes and relationships in the neo4j db since it worked really well for me with smaller set of datas but once I had it working for smaller dataset I used the same script on my entire db and at the end it hangs. My db has all the relationships and components in a single table with ID,Name, ancestry(parent) as the columns.

Comment: A batch insert would work better (if importing from CSV, you can use the periodic commit functionality to significantly speed things up)...and if that doesn't work, you'll need some way to tackle only segments at a time. Can you add your script to the description?

Comment: The script just goes through my database and creates nodes and relationships and converts them into cql. And after that I just insert those into neo4j-shell which worked nicely for smaller data but for the entire db it didn't. I'm very new to neo4j so I decided to use csv after that and I just need to know how to create the relationships between the parent and the child.

Comment: Thanks for all your help btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a large dataset, you need to combine [`USING PERIODIC COMMIT`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data) with `LOAD CSV`:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Data) ASSERT n.id IS UNIQUE

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data.csv" AS line
CREATE (n:Data {id: line.id, name: line.name})

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data.csv" AS line
MATCH (n:Data {id: line.id}), (a:Data {id: line.ancestry})
MERGE (n)-[:HAS_ANCESTOR]->(a)
```

Comment: Thanks this is very close. Do you know how long the second statement should run for? I've had it running for about 5 mins now.

Comment: It depends on how many lines there are in your CSV file, and if you actually created a unique constraint on the `id` property so the `MATCH` will be fast (using the index instead of a full node scan): [`CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Data) ASSERT n.id IS UNIQUE`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/#query-constraints-unique-nodes).

Comment: Thanks works like charm! It only goes one layer deep however, do you know how I can fix that? I have the first parent and child relationship showing as has_ancestor but the rest don't show. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Unless you purged the database or deleted all the relationships, running the second statement a second time won't create duplicate relationships since it uses [`MERGE`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/#_merge_relationships). You can purge the database by running `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n` then run the 2 steps, or only delete the relationships using `MATCH ()-[r]->() DELETE r` then run the second step. Or, just check that you do have the relationships by counting them: `MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN count(r)`.

Comment: Any `id`/`ancestry` tuple present in the CSV should have materialized as a relationship, unless some ancestors are not present as ids themselves. That was the point of the 2 steps: first create all the nodes (only based on the `id` and `name` columns), then link them. If some ancestors are not "first class" nodes, then they'd have to be created at the same time as the relationship (without a name, though).

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't go any deeper than the first parent->child relationship I have 6 layers deep in my database. It works really well for the first parent child relationship but for some reason the rest don't get created. When I do a count I notice that it's only going to the first parent child relationship but not deeper. Anyway I can make it go deeper?

Comment: I see what you mean but for some reason it works nicely for the first ancestry relationship but not the rest I checked the csv and it's not missing any ancestry id's.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I got it to work thanks to you! I'm new to neo4j so thanks for the patience

Comment: I don't see any reason why; the script doesn't even know the difference between a leaf node and an intermediate one. Take one line in your CSV file for which the relationship doesn't exist, and play it by hand, with the actual ids: `MATCH (n:Data {id: 42}), (a:Data {id: 153}) RETURN n, a` then see what's returned.

Comment: OK, we crossed comments, so mine's irrelevant now. Cool it worked out for you.

Comment: Thanks I truly appreciate the help!